# PostGIS ST_Intersects not returning values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, postgis

I recently installed the PostGIS extension for a rails app that i'm working on.
Currently, i am trying to get all the polygons that intersect the vieport of the Google Maps. 
On running the (see below) sql i get nothing. I hardcoded the values. 
I just want to mention that i'm relatively new to PostGIS; what am i doing wrong?

```
SELECT * FROM cg_dxf_shapes WHERE 
  ST_Intersects(
      gis_stereo_shape, 
      ST_Transform(
          ST_Envelope(
              ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(47.73964811979098 26.09410725402836, 47.75263376633051 26.124834640502968)',4326)
          ),
          31700
      )
  ) = TRUE
```

I've tried different variations, but with no result; even when using the 4326 SRID on both geometries.

Thanks.

Comment: Cross post here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/154557/1872

Comment: Is your geometry: `gis_stereo_shape` projected in 31700? I may be only a projection issue...

Comment: Post in the body of the question (not as comment) the result of this query:  `SELECT DISTINCT ST_srid(gis_stereo_shape) FROM cg_dxf_shapes;`

Comment: What is the results of `select  st_relate( gis_stereo_shape, ST_Transform( other_shape....) from cg_dxf_shapes`  . if return `FF*FF****` it means Disjoint.